# position: sticky doesn't work for element inside <ion-item>

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sticky, horizontal-scrolling, ion-item

I have implemented a table, which is very wide (much wider than the screen), and the user can scroll horizontally.

At the far left, is a task-row component which has an element with a “sticky” header (.task-row_main class), which doesn't move when scrolling horizontally, by using the css `position: sticky`.

```
.task-row_main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 230px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 1px;
}
```

When I add my task-row component into `ion-item`, the sticky header breaks. Scrolling horizontally causes the sticky header to scroll off screen.

```
<ion-item>
    <task-row>
    </task-row>
</ion-item>
```

But when I dont wrap it in an `ion-item`, it works:

```
<task-row>
</task-row>
```

How do I make it so that position: sticky works for element inside an `<ion-item>`?

Comment: can you apply sticky to ion-item?

Answer (score 1):

Try this may be this can fix your problem, if you will take left:0px and right:0px; then it will take 100% width.

```
.ion-item{
  position:relative;
}
.task-row {
    position: sticky;
    left:1px;
    top: 0px;
    right:0px
}
```

Comment: Can you please upload your code in codepen and send me link.